# Ruby array reverse_each_with_index

Tags: ruby

I would like to use something like `reverse_each_with_index` on an array.

Example:

```
array.reverse_each_with_index do |node,index|
  puts node
  puts index
end
```

I see that Ruby has `each_with_index` but it doesn’t seem to have an opposite. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you tell me what the output you want to have?

Comment: Are you asking how to use an (non-)existing method called `reverse_each_with_index`, or want to implement one that has a certain function? Different portions of your question imply one or the other.

Answer (score 56):

If you want the real index of the element in the array you can do this

```
['Seriously', 'Chunky', 'Bacon'].to_enum.with_index.reverse_each do |word, index|
  puts "index #{index}: #{word}"
end
```

Output:

```
index 2: Bacon
index 1: Chunky
index 0: Seriously
```

You can also define your own reverse_each_with_index method

```
class Array
  def reverse_each_with_index &block
    to_enum.with_index.reverse_each &block
  end
end

['Seriously', 'Chunky', 'Bacon'].reverse_each_with_index do |word, index|
  puts "index #{index}: #{word}"
end
```

An optimized version

```
class Array
  def reverse_each_with_index &block
    (0...length).reverse_each do |i|
      block.call self[i], i
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the only variant except for `(array.size - 1).downto(0)` that lets you `delete_at(index)` during enumeration. The other solutions at the time of me writing this will not produce stable indices.

Answer (score 21):

First `reverse` the array, and then use `each_with_index`:

```
array.reverse.each_with_index do |element, index|
  # ...
end
```

Although, indexes will go from `0` to `length - 1`, not the other way around.

Comment: this creates a copy of the array, doesn't it?

Comment: It certainly does.

Answer (score 11):

Without copying array:

```
(array.size - 1).downto(0) do |index|
  node = array[index]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: By far the fastest way! Sometimes old plain integer iterations are better than fancy iterators. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I think this is best so far. It's really a shame ruby doesn't have a more intuitive way.

Answer (score 9):

Well since Ruby always likes to give you options you can not only do:

```
arr.reverse.each_with_index do |e, i|

end
```

but you can also do:

```
arr.reverse_each.with_index do |e, i|

end
```

Comment: I'd expect `.reverse_each.with_index` to be faster, since `.reverse_each` is faster than `.reverse.each`. I would therefore use `.reverse_each.with_index` and reverse the indexes myself, or use the reversed index as a negative array lookup. Although brief experimentation did not show a big difference in my irb.

Comment: `arr.reverse_each.with_index do |e, i|

end`  doesn't work for what the op is asking for. This will yield the forward ordered  indexes [0,1,2 etc]

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
arr.reverse.each_with_index do |node, index|
```

Answer (score 2):

The real correct answer is like the following.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.each_with_index.reverse_each {|e, i|
  p [i, e]
}
```

This gives the following output.

```
[2, "c"]
[1, "b"]
[0, "a"]
```

As a side note, this has worked on Ruby 1.9.3(around 2011) and later at least.

Comment: Thanks! It works also with hash

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer. Clean, to the point, and (probably) highly performant.

Comment: Did anyone test this for performance? I wonder if this is reversing something in there.

Comment: The merit of this answer is brevity and readability. This will create a temporary array, so it will be slower than the answer of Pavel Evstigneev.

Answer (score 0):

in my usecase I wanted to iterate backwards using negative indexes

```rb
a = %w[a b c] 
(1..a.size).each {|i| puts "-#{i}: #{a[-i]}"}
# => -1: c
# => -2: b
# => -3: a
```